# How can I use the surrounding page's style for a link, in a custom element?

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a custom `<my-header>` element that generates a link in shadow dom, which I'd like to have styled the same as the other links in the surrounding page.  The old `applyAuthorStyles` attribute was a decent way to accomplish that, although it had its [own problems](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=23625). Now that `applyAuthorStyles` has been removed, the option I see is to have embedders define their global styles as:

```css
a, * ^ a { color: green; }
```

and so on, which intrudes into the styles of elements that don't want the page's styles.

Is there a better way to do this?

I have some sample code at http://jsbin.com/yusox/1/edit and below. You'll only see the inconsistency if your browser has native Shadow DOM turned on (chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features in Chrome).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.1.4/platform.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.1.4/polymer.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
  body {max-width: 50ch;}
  a { color: green; text-decoration:none; border-bottom: 1px blue dashed ; }
  a:visited { color: darkgreen;}
</style>
<polymer-element name="my-header" noscript attributes="sec_num">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host { display: block; }
      header { font-weight: bold; margin: 20px 0; }
      header::after { clear:both; display: block; content: " "; height: 0 }
    </style>

    <header>
      <span class="section-number">{{sec_num}}</span>
      <content></content>
      <span style="float:right"><a href="#{{id}}">[{{id}}]</a></span>
    </header>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
</head>
<body>
  <my-header id="first.section" sec_num="1.2">Foo Bar Baz</my-header>
  <a href="http://www.polymer-project.org/">Polymer</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> intrudes into the styles of elements that don't want the page's styles.

Yes, intrusion will happen if you use `*`, so instead drive the style for your specific element:

`a, my-header ^ a, body ^^ my-header ^ a { .. }`

Fwiw, I don't think anybody is in love with this syntax, but that's the CSS that is supported today.

There are fancier solutions involving additional custom elements to manage dynamic, shared style-sheets, but it's a larger topic. Polymer will offer some kind of solution around these lines before long.

Comment: And to double-check, everything that's possible today is driven from the document stylesheet outside-in rather than the polymer-element being able to pull styles from its context?

Comment: The answer is yes, but there is some nuance. It's possible for an element to style itself based on the structure above it (i.e. you can build selectors that examine containing DOM), but there is no concept in CSS (even outside of ShadowDOM) that allows a selector to pull in rules from another place.